# Make an oauth Request to fetch data from WooCommerce-api in React native

Tags: authentication, reactjs, oauth, react-native, woocommerce-rest-api

I have installed WooCommerce on a remote server.

In WooCommerce> Settings> API, I have created a Consumer key and consumer secret.

Now I have created a React native app and I want to fetch the data from WooCommerce API and display it in the app.

I tried the Woocommerce-API npm package but that package is not compatible with React native and I am getting the following error:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968

So I found another npm package named [react-native-oauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-oauth)

While using this I get the following error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):

YellowBox.js:68 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1): Provider React App Key not configured Error: Provider React App Key not configured
    at createErrorFromErrorData (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7761:11)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7712:11
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7575:10)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7437:8
    at guard (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7349:1)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7436:1)
    at onmessage (http://localhost:8081/debuggerWorker.js:39:56)
```

So I am stuck at this point and have no idea how to make an oauth request to WooCommerce API and fetch the data. I researched a lot on it but cannot find the perffect doc which will make understand the whole authentication process.

It would be really helpful if anyone would post the detailed solution for this issue!

Thank you.